# How Do I Type A Message In Messenger With VBScript?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I've set up a script to run that opens messenger, runs through an array of people to send a message to, and sends each of them a pre-recorded text message (saved in numbered files). The problem is that I'm doing all of this through the Shell, and it's very sloppy. It works to an extent, but I'm looking for a better way to do it that's cleaner and works on its own so I don't have to babysit it. I'm including the current working code, and then the code I want to work, and then I'll focus on what's broken that I need help with.

Here's my current working code:

```
Dim messenger, readFile(1), str1, date1, date2, days

date2 = Date
date1 = "12-Dec-19"
days = DateDiff("d", date1, date2)

messenger=Array(...)
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForReading = 1
Set obj1 = obj.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Sherman\Documents\Message\Day" & days & ".txt", ForReading)
readFile(0) = obj1.ReadAll
readFile(1) = "{ENTER}"
str1 = Join(readFile)

For i = 0 To UBound(messenger)
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("https://www.messenger.com/t/" & messenger(i))
    WScript.Sleep 12500
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys str1
    WScript.Sleep 2000
Next

obj1.Close
Set obj=Nothing
```

This code works with my default browser, which is Opera (but could work with whatever I set as the default), but it can't wait for the browser to finish loading, which would be neater. So I had to do what I don't like, and use IE with this script:

```
Dim messenger, readFile(1), str1, date1, date2, days, IE

date2 = Date
date1 = "12-Dec-19"
days = DateDiff("d", date1, date2)

messenger=Array(...)
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForReading = 1
Set obj1 = obj.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Sherman\Documents\Message\Day" & days & ".txt", ForReading)
readFile(0) = obj1.ReadAll
readFile(1) = "{ENTER}"
str1 = Join(readFile)

For i = 0 To UBound(messenger)
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .visible = true
        .navigate "https://www.messenger.com/t/" & messenger(i)
        While .Busy
            WScript.sleep 100
        Wend
        .getElementsByName("span data-text='true'").value = str1 '<-This is where the error occurs'
        WScript.Sleep 30000 'give time for shell to type out the message'            
    end With
    IE.Close  'not sure if this works or not because the error occurs before I get here'
Next    
obj1.Close
```

I can create a shell object as above to send the message, but for some reason, rather than sending it as a block of text like in the first code, it actually takes the time to type out each character (very annoying!). The text field is contained in a span, which is contained in another span. So I can't just target the  tag to send the message. Also, there's no id to target with .getElementById. And the error I get says "Object doesn't support this property or method" even though I've seen other threads about VBScript that use the .getElementsByName method.

Next, I want to close each browser instance before starting another one. And closing the browser window seems for some reason to be a lot more complicated than opening it.

Am I making this too complicated? Is there a simpler way that works better at sending automated messages to multiple people? Should I give up on VBScript altogether and use something else? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When using the getElementsByName or getElementsByClassName method, it will return an array-like object which have the same Name and Class name. If we want to access the specific element, we could find it via the array index (start from 0). like this:

```
.Document.getElementsByName("q").Item(0).Value = "Foxtrot RPA" 'Write something to search for.
```

> Next, I want to close each browser instance before starting another
>   one. And closing the browser window seems for some reason to be a lot
>   more complicated than opening it.

To close the specific tab, you could try to use the `IE.Quit` method.

Reference: [How-To Automate IE With VBScript](https://support.foxtrotalliance.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023770832-How-To-Automate-IE-With-VBScript)

Comment: VBScript is typeless, it doesn't understand `As Object` and it has no concept of `DoEvents`

Comment: @Lankymart, Thanks for reminding me about that, the previous code is VBA script, it is my mistake. I have changed my reply. please check it.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT, thanks for your response. How do I check to make sure I have the right item? I tried this, but it returned an error: 
`Set ele = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("_5rpb").Item(5) 
MsgBox ele.innerHTML 
MsgBox ele.outerHTML`
 Also, I notice that before I start typing, the innerhtml on the line where the code is types only containes a <br> tag. But once someone starts typing, it dynamically changes to a <span> tag. So I need to target the next tag up and work with that one, correct?

Comment: @Sherman, To the first question, from your code, you want to find the elements by class name. So, you could check your application code which element has the same class name. Besides, you could also use F12 developer tools to check the web page elements and check the class name. To the second question, by using your code it will dynamically change the innerHtml,  the <br> tag inserts a single line break, and the <span> tag is used to insert text, perhaps someone has inserted some text. Might be you should add some limitation to let only one user to modify the content at the same time.